# How to locally turn off phpmd rule in a comment?

Tags: php, phpmd

How can I locally disable a single phpmd rule for a few lines and then re-enable a rule, for example the `unusedcode`?

Answer (score 8):

PHPMD calls this [Warning Suppression](http://phpmd.org/documentation/suppress-warnings.html). Warnings Suppression granularity is that of one function scope. Comments are added to the function/class docblock, and therefore apply to that docblock's scope.

In a function doc block you can add `@SuppressWarnings(unused)` keyword.

From their [examples](http://phpmd.org/documentation/suppress-warnings.html):

```
<?php
/**
 * Suppress all rules containing "unused" in this
 * class
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 */
class Bar {
    private $unusedPrivateField = 42;
    public function foo($unusedFormalParameter = 23)
    {
        $unusedLocalVariable = 17;
    }
    private function unusedPrivateMethod() {
    }
}
```

Rule names are not explicitly listed for use so some notes on valid names:

Some notes about warning names:

- `unused` Is the supression name for the rules that ruleset `runusedcode` reports.
- `PHPMD` is a top level name that can suppress all phpmd warnings for a block.
- `PHPMD.<rulename>` where `<rulename>` is one of the link names from [the rules doc](http://phpmd.org/rules/index.html) work.